# Wordpress: Getting an error uploading file size greater than 30MB

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-8

I have these settings:

```
post_max_size = 120M
upload_max_filesize = 110M
max_execution_time = 10800
max_input_time = 10800
```

I have `PHP 7.0.2` running on `IIS`. Why would I be getting an error when uploading files larger than 30MB?

Comment: As a quick work around you could copy/move the file(s) into the wordpress directory on the server.

Comment: did you confirm that those settings actually took effect? `phpinfo()` will show you what's really in effect.

Comment: Yes I can. That was going to be my last resort.

Comment: @MarcB Just confirmed. It is reflecting the values I set.

Comment: Can you give us the specific error?